# Quartz Scheduler - trigger does not reference given job

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler

I'm using the Quartz Scheduler in my application and I get the exception: Trigger does not reference the given job...

Looking at my code I can't seem to see where the problem could be.

```
    var schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();

    IJobDetail dailyJob = JobBuilder.Create<PushElectricityPricesJob>()
        .WithIdentity("dailyJob", "group1")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
       .WithIdentity("dailyJobTrigger", "group1")
       .StartNow()
       .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(3, 0))
       .ForJob("dailyJob")
       .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(dailyJob, trigger1);

    IJobDetail monthlyJob = JobBuilder.Create<PushContributionsJob>()
        .WithIdentity("monthlyJob", "group2")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("monthlyJobTrigger", "group2")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.MonthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(1, 0, 0))             
        .ForJob("monthlyJob")
        .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(monthlyJob, trigger2);

    scheduler.Start();
```

I did found a lot of posts like this one on StackOverflow but on each of them I could spot the mistake or typo that the dev made. Here I'm just stuck clueless..

Any idea?

Comment: Are you getting the same exception for both triggers or just one or the other?

Comment: I tried with one at a time (tried both of course) and it fails as much as with both

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok found it!

Problem was because of the groups. The WithIdentity method can be called without specifying the group, just with the name.

So it becomes:

```
IJobDetail dailyJob = JobBuilder.Create<PushElectricityPricesJob>()
    .WithIdentity("dailyJob")
    .Build();

ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
   .WithIdentity("dailyJobTrigger")
   .StartNow()
   .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(3, 0))
   .ForJob("dailyJob")
   .Build();
```

And that seems to work fine.
Of course you need to do the same for the other job.

Answer (score 0):

delete 
.ForJob("dailyJob")

or change to other

Comment: please add some explanation to make answer useful to others as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the same group used on jobDetail.withIdentity("job01", "group1") on trigger.forJob("job01", "group1")

The Trigger need to be informed wich group your Job is using, for example:

```
    var schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    scheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();

    IJobDetail dailyJob = JobBuilder.Create<PushElectricityPricesJob>()
        .WithIdentity("dailyJob", "group1")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
       .WithIdentity("dailyJobTrigger", "group1")
       .StartNow()
       .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(3, 0))
       .ForJob("dailyJob", "group1")
       .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(dailyJob, trigger1);
```

Beside this it will think that its using the DEFAULT group and will not work.

Comment: It might help to edit your answer to include examples based on the code.  If I understand correctly, what you're saying is that they should replace the ".ForJob("dailyJob")" with ".ForJob("dailyJob, group1")" and do something similar for the monthlyJob?

Answer (score 0):

The error basically means: `JobKey` defined in `JobDetail` doesn't match with `JobKey` defined in `Trigger`. So, make:

```
JobBuilder.withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey("ABC")) 
TriggerBuilder.withIdentity(JobKey.jobKey("ABC"))
```

Obviously you have to make both the group names same as well; or remove both

Answer (score 0):

You should add group name in With Identity() Job and trigger.
Job

```
 JobBuilder
.Create<BackupJob>()
.WithIdentity(todo.Name,"group1")
.WithDescription(todo.Name)
.Build();
```

Trigger

```
JobBuilder
.Create<BackupJob>()
.WithIdentity(todo.Name,"group1")
.WithDescription(todo.Name)
.Build();
```